# What are the differences in the word orders?

Tags: word-order

All the sentences are correct?
What is the difference between them?

1. I *often* go to the cafe.
2. *Often*, I go to the cafe.
3. I go to the cafe *often*.

---

4. I have the phone *only*.
5. I *only* have the phone.
6. I have *only* the phone.
7. *Only* I have the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I only teach you" vs. "I teach only you" vs. "I teach you only".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/i-only-teach-you-vs-i-teach-only-you-vs-i-teach-you-only) Also [Place of only acting as adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117154/) and [Where to place 'only'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/) and [How can the position of 'only' change the meaning of a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93284/) and [position of 'only' and the respective change in meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27595/)...

Comment: @FumbleFingers the first link says: "I teach you only."
"This sentence seems incomplete or is phrased by a non-native English speaker." Is that right? If so, then "I have the phone only." is incomplete?

Comment: "Are all the sentences correct?"

Comment: “I teach you only” means that I teach you but nobody else.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: But people have always been loose about the placement of ***only***, and some would convey exactly the same meaning with *I **only** teach you*. And here's [*I borrowed it **only***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+borrowed+it+only+though%22) - clearly meaning *I only borrowed (didn't **steal**) it*, not *It was the only thing I borrowed*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, absolutely. I was replying to the suggestion that *I teach you only* “seems incomplete or is phrased by a non-native English speaker.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: *... incomplete or nns **OR dated/literary***. The first clear-cut example I found in Google Books was C19: [*You must believe now that I love you only.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22believe+now+that+i+love+you+only%22)

Answer (score 2):

Sentences 1–3 have essentially the same meaning. But shifting the position of *only* cannot be done so freely. Although sentences 4–6 have essentially the same meaning, specifying your single possession, sentence 7 means instead that nobody else besides you possesses it.

Comment: If I substitute "often" with "sometime" or "always", nothing changes?

Comment: *Sometime**s*** and *always* are like *often* because all three of them  have a single sense—that of specifying a temporal frequency. That’s why their sentences like 1–3 are fairly insensitive to their placement. By contrast, *only* can modify verbs, their subjects and objects, and objects of prepositions. So its location in a sentence is more tightly constrained by one’s intended meaning.

Comment: "Always I go..." wouldn't be used in ordinary conversation, though it might possibly be valid in literature.

Comment: @KateBunting "Always I go..." is correct but not natural?

Comment: It's grammatical, but not idiomatic, except possibly in poetry. If you used it in conversation it would give you away as a non-native speaker.